# How to get the urls from bluestacks

Tags: fiddler, bluestacks

I would like to get data from bluestacks.

I installed Fiddler.

When I clicked the apps, I only see cloud.bluestacks.com but not a url from which the data in the apps loaded.

How to get the urls I want?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Have you configured Bluestacks to use your proxy? Have you installed the Fiddler Root CA certificate into Bluestacks?

Comment: I am new to this area. Can you show me the steps?